# Настройки mbstring через Apache

Tags: веб-сервер, .htaccess, php, debian, apache2

Суть в том, что я хочу изменять настройки модуля **php mbstring**  через конфигурационные файлы Apache, но что-то не дает мне это сделать.

Конфигурация **Debian 6** + **Apache/2.2.20** + **PHP Version 5.3.8-1+b1** (установлен как модуль Apache, *php_sapi_name()* возвращает *apache2handler*) 
Директива **AllowOverride** установлена в **All** в файле hosts (каталога sites-available).

Сначала я пытался проверять установку переменной **mbmbstring.func_overload** через **get_cfg_var()**, но потом прочитал [вот здесь](http://php.su/functions/?get-cfg-var), что данная функция не читает конфигурацию из файла Apache.
После чего стал проверять установку **mbmbstring.func_overload** следующим нехитрым преобразованием:

```
$strForTest = "Тестовая строка";var_dump($strForTest);var_dump(substr($strForTest, 0, 4));var_dump(mb_substr($strForTest, 0, 4));
```

Следует заметить, что сам файл в кодировке **UTF-8** и на сервере выставлено **AddDefaulCharset utf-8**.
Если установлено значение **mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8** но значение **mbmbstring.func_overload 0** правильно работает только функция **mb_substr()**
Если установить еще и **mbmbstring.func_overload 2** обе функции работают верно.
Таким образом я и тестирую какие переменные установлены.

Вот только одно но, ни установка значений

```
php_value mbstring.func_overload 2php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
```

в .htaccess, или в hosts для хоста, или в apache2.conf для всего сервера - ни дает ровным счетом ничего.

Так же ничего не дает использование **php_admin_value** вместо **php_value**.

Хорошо, допустим непонятно имеет ли переменная **mbmbstring.func_overload** режим **PHP_INI_PERDIR** или **PHP_INI_SYSTEM**. Но даже если и **PHP_INI_SYSTEM**, почему она не устанавливается из файла глобальных настроек Apache?.. В любом случае, переменная **mbstring.internal_encoding** имеет режим **PHP_INI_ALL** однако тоже не хочет устанавливаться из любых конфигурационных файлов Apache. Что наводит меня на мысль, что какая-то настройка PHP или Apache запрещает в принципе менять директивы PHP, но какая?.. Пару дней шерстил интернет - ничего, что могло бы мне помочь, не нашел, теперь обращаюсь к вам.

Comment: Насчет __mbstring.func\_overload__ отбой.  Во первых, настройки mbstring больше нельзя устанавливать в .htaccess, во вторых? она чудом заработала из файла настроек для хоста.  Но по прежнему не работает __mbstring.internal\_encoding__ - она никак не хочет устанавливаться, ни через php\_value, ни через php\_admin\_value, ни UTF-8, ни utf-8, ни UTF8, ни utf8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно может не ставиться в случаях, если не установлена локаль `utf8php_value mbstring.internal_encoding utf8` для меня сработало.

По возможности проверьте в командной строке `$ locale -a`.